# Using Rails 4, need help making a better sidebar menu for navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a sidebar menu and I've been having some issues implementing some of the features. I'm a complete noob at this and I'm having issues implementing an active page indicator for the dashboard. The sidebar is a partial and I had trouble finding resources for implementing an active page indicator on a partial. I am also using Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find the `link_to` and `current_page?` helpers for what you're trying to do very useful, as well as the ordinary `a` and `href` html tags. I suggest looking at the rails documentation for more information on those helpers.

Here's an example with a bootstrap navbar, where clicking on a navbar entry links you to a certain page (the dashboard located in views/home/dashboard.html.erb in this case), and if it is the current "active" page, highlight it. I don't know how to implement rails snippets in Jsfiddle, my apologies, but hopefully it gives you an idea:

```
<!-- Some irrelevant Bootstrap navbar code before this -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand <%= 'active' if current_page?(root_path) %>" href="/">My Company Text</a>
</div>

<!-- ... More navbar code ... -->
<!-- A drop-down with a Font Awesome icon example below -->
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li>
    <%= link_to home_dashboard_path, class: 'user' do %>
      <i class="fa fa-tachometer">&nbsp;</i>My Dashboard
    <% end %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, got the active page indicator done.